# find - how do i make an alias to do something like (find . -iname '*$1*')?

Tags: find, alias, xargs, function

I have a `findn` function:

```
findn () {
    find . -iname "*$1*"
}
```

Using this function has one downside that I cannot use `-print0 | xargs -0 command` (I am using mac) following `findn filename` to extend the functionality of the find command if the filename contains empty spaces.

So, is there anyway I can keep both the functions of handy `-iname "*$1*"` and `| xargs command` at the same time?

I was thinking of using an alias to do it, but it doesn't have to be an alias.

Comment: What problem did you have using xargs with the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with GNU `find` or compatible (`-iname` is already a GNU extension anyway) could be to define the function as:

```
findn() (
  if [ -t 1 ]; then # if the output goes to a terminal
    action=-print  # simple print for the user to see
  else
    action=-print0 # NUL-delimited records so the output can be post-processed
  fi
  first=true
  for arg do
    if "$first"; then
      set -- "$@" '('
      first=false
    else
      set -- "$@" -o
    fi
    set -- "$@" -iname "*$arg*"
    shift
  done
  "$first" || set -- "$@" ')'
  exec find . "$@" "$action"
)
```

Then you can use it as:

```
findn foo bar
```

To *see* the file names that contain `foo` or `bar` (change the `-o` to `-a` above if you want instead the ones that contain both `foo` *and* `bar`).

And:

```
findn foo bar | xargs -r0 cat
```

If you want to apply a command on each file found by `findn`.

For a variant that does both *and* and *not*:

```
findn() (
  if [ -t 1 ]; then # if the output goes to a terminal
    action=-print  # simple print for the user to see
  else
    action=-print0 # NUL-delimited records so the output can be post-processed
  fi
  first=true
  for arg do
    if "$first"; then
      set -- "$@" '('
      first=false
    else
      set -- "$@"
    fi
    if [ "$arg" = ! ]; then
      set -- "$@" !
    else
      case $arg in
        (*[][*?\\]*)
          # already contains wildcard characters, don't wrap in *
          set -- "$@" -iname "$arg"
          ;;
        (*)
          set -- "$@" -iname "*$arg*"
          ;;
      esac
    fi
    shift
  done
  "$first" || set -- "$@" ')'
  exec find . "$@" "$action"
)
```

And then:

```
findn foo bar ! baz
```

For the filenames that contain both `foo` and `bar` and not `baz`.

In that variant, I also made it so that if the argument contained a wildcard character, it was taken as-is, so you can do:

```
findn foo ! 'bar*'
```

To look for files that do not *start* with bar. If you're using the `zsh` shell, you can make an alias:

```
alias findn='noglob findn'
```

To disable globbing on that command which allows you to write:

```
find foo ! bar*
```

You may want to make that a script (here a `sh` script is enough as that syntax is POSIX) instead of a function, so it can be called from anywhere instead of just your shell.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution works just fine with `xargs`:

```
$ echo "foo bar one" > foobarone
$ echo "foo bar two" > fooBARtwo
$ findn "bar"
./fooBARtwo
./foobarone
$ findn "bar" | xargs cat
foo bar two
foo bar one
```

Or is there anything I have missed?

And if you modify your function a little bit, you could add additional parameters to your `find` command:

```
findn () {
  local name=$1
  shift
  find . -iname "*$name*" "$@"
}
```

Example:

```
$ findn bar ! -name '*two' -print0 | xargs -0 cat
foo bar one
```

Comment: `find | xargs` without `-print0`/`-0` should *not* be used. It fails if the file names contain white space or quotes or backslashes. No need for that non-standard `-print0`/`-0` anyway. With your improved `findn` command, you can just do `findn bar -exec cat {} +`